# What is preventing python from recognizing my relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path

I am taking an online course in Python. I am using version 3.8.1 on Windows. I am trying to write a program which will retrieve the size of all the files within a certain folder. My current working directory is 'c:\'. This is the code I have written:

```
for filename in os.listdir('c:\\mypythonscripts'):
if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join('c:\\mypythonscripts', filename)):
    continue
totalSize = totalSize + os.path.getsize(os.path.join('c:\\mypythonscripts', filename))
```

This is the error message it produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir('c:\\mypythonscripts'):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:\\mypythonscripts'
```

The spelling of the file name is correct and I am able to retrieve the file size when I use an absolute path:

```
for filename in os.listdir('c:\\users\\owner\\mypythonscripts'):
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join('c:\\users\\owner\\mypythonscripts', filename)):
        continue
    totalSize = totalSize + os.path.getsize(os.path.join('c:\\users\\owner\\mypythonscripts', filename))


>>> totalSize
2281314
```

Can someone tell me what is preventing Python from recognizing the relative path?

Comment: The fact that you have `c:\\\` in front means it is *not* a relative path, but an absolute one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the script from the `mypythonscripts` directory you can go `os.listdir('.')`.

If you're running the script from the `owner` directory, you can go `os.listdir('mypythonscripts')`.